# What's 'my local area' mean? Can it be my hometown?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In an EAL test, the examiner would ask me whether I am studying or working, so the examiner would know that I am working and I live in Melbourne for the majority of my time.

Then the examiner might ask me to describe a change that will improve **my local area**. In this case, can I talk about the change that is going to happen in **my hometown**? (I didn't follow the news closely, so although I live in Melbourne, I cannot think of any change that is going to happen... )

Given that I live in Melbourne now, does '**my hometown**' still considered as '**my local area**', or '**local area**' has to be the place I'm currently living?

Is it acceptable to say 'I can't think of any change that is going to happen in Melbourne, so I will talk about a positive change that is going to happen in my hometown'?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your hometown close to Melbourne? Some people consider their hometown to be where they grew up, not where they are living now. For example, if my parents raised me in Texas but I now live in Ottowa, I might say that my hometown is Dallas but my (current) local area is the Toronto metropolitan region. I think your *local area* refers to where you are living now – not necessarily the city limits, but any place around there you could reach in 30 minutes by car.

Comment: @J.R. My hometown is not close to Melbourne haha, otherwise I won't be taking the EAL test. English is not my first language.

Comment: In that case, I think "local area" refers to where you are currently living.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, your

> local area

is the area around where you currently reside since by living there you are considered a *local*.

Your

> hometown

is where you grew up.  For some, their *hometown* is their *local area*, but if you've moved away from home then it is not your *local area*.

Sometimes people may ask you questions about your *local area* in order to figure out how familiar you really are with the area and whether you actually know as much as someone who has lived there for a period of time.

Whether you can change the subject of the question would partly depend on what the intention of the question is in the first place.